# Can we compile procedure or function if there is DDL lock on that procedure?

Tags: plsql

procedure cannot be compiled? it is just running and nothing happened.
and I have try following code to check whether any block session make this. but I did not find any blocked session.
select
*
from
v$session
where
blocking_session is not NULL
order by
blocking_session;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find it as a blocking session, nor in gv$lock, because it's a library object lock rather than a data object lock. Instead, look at `gv$access` and/or `dba_ddl_locks`. You can also look at `gv$session` for a `plsql_object_id` or `plsql_entry_object_id` matching the object_id of your procedure in either dba_objects or dba_procedures. That's not a sure-fire way of catching everything though, if you have chained PL/SQL calls... but gv$access and/or dba_ddl_locks will have what you need for sure.

If something is executing your procedure, you will have to wait for them to complete, or kill their session, before you can compile it. It's a weak point in Oracle, that prevents us from pushing code changes in without kicking everybody out first. But that's the way it is.

Comment: I think it is a PGA (process global area) block proces and all the transactions are in waiting status.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a lot of rows in the table and whenever I try to compile procedure it can call that table too. So I Stop the compilation process at that time and execute the rollback statement. Therefore it takes time to rollback milions of rows one by one I have tracked those process through the following script.

```
select s.sid, s.serial#, s.client_info, t.addr, sum(t.used_ublk)
from v$transaction t, v$session s
where t.addr = s.taddr
group by s.sid, s.serial#, s.client_info, t.addr;
```

I just need to wait and might be I did not find any idea about to do anything except waiting. When all the transactions are rollbacked then I try to compile it and it compiled.

Comment: Compiling a procedure has no effect on rows in a table. If you were seeing a rollback, it was due to something other than a procedure compilation. But glad to hear you were able to move on.